# Methods for measuring line/with buffer overlap

Tags: qgis, arcgis-desktop

I have about 250 routes and I want to know how many meters of the routes overlap with each other relative to the total meters traveled.

I have a buffer around each route so it is really how much of the buffers overlap if that helps.

I can provide sample data if that helps.

Comment: Including a few images to show exactly what you're looking for would definitely help. You can edit your question to show the screenshots.

Comment: Please pick a single software package. By tagging your question with both QGIS and Arcgis-desktop, you're effectively asking two different questions.